# Blazor CSS not loading

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-3.1

We've been using Blazor for a few months with Radzen and recently Spinkit. I merged some changes from master into my features branch and the system now can't resolve css from the packages. The changes merged were completely isolated from Blazor specific code, just injected service classes not related to web, as well as moving Autofac registrations to the Program.cs. I just can't put my finger on what could have gone wrong. If I hard reset back to the branch prior all is good. I've been over it a few times but just can't work it out. This is the Chrome console output:
[image]

We have this CSS in the head of _Host.cshtml:

```
<link href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/default-base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="_content/BlazorPro.Spinkit/spinkit.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and these scripts at the end of body

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js"></script>
```

We're using Radzen.Blazor 2.11.14 and BlazorPro.Spinkit 1.2.0 on netcoreapp3.1.

Anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Try to invert scripts declaration order

Comment: Unfortunately it made no difference

Comment: try to clean remove all obj, bin and .vs folder and rebuild

Comment: Thanks for the advice. These are steps I always try. I found the answer  to my specific issue and posted here.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out an incoming change from master had this in launchsettings.json

```
 "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Local"
      }
    },
```

I switched `local` back to `development` which fixed the issue.
We wanted to put AzureDevOps Personal Access Tokens in a git ignored file called appsettings.local.json. I guess that obvious option is out the window.

Anyone know why this breaks the pipeline?
The ridiculous part is the entire site works normally without other errors. It just stops nuget packages from loading (at runtime) and gives no message about it. I'm not sure if this is a Blazor, Razor or ASP.NET Core MVC issue.

This coupled with a few other issues I've hit have convinced me that Blazor is incomplete to the point of being unusable for an enterprise project. Is early days for us so a switch to a real SPA platform is being worked into our backlog.

Comment: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT defines the environment you use and then selects the configuration override file (*appsettings.{environment}.json*). If you configure your authentication for Azure in  *appsettings.Development.json* and you define *Local* as environment , Blazor try to load *appsettings.Local.json* and don't find it.

Comment: In your Azure app service define configurations variables you need. This will set environment variables overriding the configuration for your server. However, that doesn't override the *appsettings.{environment}.json* file loaded by Blazor. But you can create a custom middleware to override the response, or copy a file while deploy

Comment: Or you can just set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Local in your Azure app service configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where is switched to a page with a parameter in its URL (e.g. `page/customer/$id`. When I reloaded the page, all my CSS would disappear. Turns out in `_Host.cshtml` you need to define `<base href="~/" />` before any of your links to stylesheets.

For example (Loads CSS);

```
<head>
<base href="~/" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Does NOT load CSS;

```
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<base href="~/" />
```

The `base href` needs to be defined before anything else.

Hope this helps someone.